# Why code block is never called?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I have function to put photos to Firebase Storage:

```
func SendAdvertisesToFireBase(_ data: SkelbimasModel) {
    var links = [String]()
    for image in data.nuotraukos {
        print(image)
        if let uploadData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) {
            //let imageNames = NSUUID().uuidString
            let store = Storage.storage().reference().child("images").child("image.png")
            store.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
                if (error != nil) {
                    print(error as Any)
                    print("nepaejo")
                    return
                }
                print("paejo")
                let address = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
                links.append(address!)
            })
        }
    }
    self.AddDataAfterImageAdded(self.skelbimas, links)
}
```

`print(image)` prints an image.

`let store =Storage.storage().reference().child("images").child("image.png"` in debugger shows that got a reference, but `store.putData(...)` is not called. I've got no errors.

Comment: How do you you know that it isn't executed?  I note that you are calling `AaddDataAfterImageAdded` and passing in `links` but `links` won't be updated until some time later since you are updating it in the closure that executes asynchronously when the upload is done.

Comment: Yes it is called. Sorry i just noticed now. But then how to pass links to addDataAfterImageAdded()?

Comment: You could use a dispatch group and dispatch group notify.

Comment: can u explain?:/